# Choosing Zero Chemical Potential

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

After asking this question: [Grand canonical ensemble and chemical potential $\mu=0$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/467669/grand-canonical-ensemble-and-chemical-potential-mu-0), 
I'm still confused about chemical potential: when have we the freedom to take $\mu=0$?

In other words, by changing the origin of energies are we always free to choose $\mu=0$ or is there some misconception in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In grand canonical ensemble, we use chemical potential to fix the average number of particles in the system. The average number $N$ is some function of temperature $T$, volume $V$ and chemical potential $\mu$, and $N = \frac{\partial G}{\partial \mu}$ where $G$ is the Gibbs free energy. When the chemical potential is zero, you cannot specify the average number of particle independently - it is now a function of $T$ and $V$ only.

You can set $\mu = 0$ by moving the origin of the potential as you say, but physically that has no meaning, the number just happens to be zero. So as always, the difference you measure between the measured potential and the origin is what matters and if that is zero, you cannot specify the average number of the particles independently.

A particular consequence of zero chemical potential is that you cannot achieve Bose-Einstein condensation. As you lower the temperature, the average particle number decreases and you don't achieve macroscopic occupation of the ground state. I paraphrased this from the introductory paragraph from this [review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7707) on Bose-Einstein condensation of photons.

Comment: So If I don't misunderstand, we have not the freedom to take $\mu=0$.