# Which chemical potentials are important?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, standard-model, chemical-potential

Reading [this SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/467669/) and some others, the following question popped up in my mind: in order to faithfully describe a relativistic quantum system with statistical mechanics/thermodynamics, which chemical potentials should be included in the (say) internal energy? I am imagining that conserved quantum numbers (baryon, electric charge, isospin, etc) should be enough, like

$$
U=TS-pV+\mu_BN_B + \mu_QQ+\mu_3I_3+\cdots
$$

instead of having to specify a chemical potential for each particle, since some would be zero (in the case of photons) or could be combined into the conserved quantities ($N_u-N_d=2I_3$ for up/down quarks and isospin, etc).

Am I thinking correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of **MaxEntropy** techique chemical potentials are a Lagrange multipliers, corresponding to a certain conserved quantity. Say, you consider the system, with fixed net energy and several more $N$ conserved quantities $Q_I,  I = 1, 2, \ldots N$.

Then the probability distribution of states with maximum entropy, subject to the condition, that these conserved quantities obtain some fixed value:
$$
\max \left(-\sum p_i \log p_i\right) \quad \text{such that} \quad
\sum_{i} p_i = 1, \sum_{i} p_i E_i = E, \sum_{i} p_i Q_{I, i} = Q_I
$$
can be obtained via method of Lagrange multipliers:
$$
-\sum_{i} p_i (\log p_i + \lambda + \beta E_i + \beta \sum_I \mu_I Q_I) 
$$
This maximization problem is solved by the **grand canonical distribution**:
$$
p_i = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta(E_i + \sum \mu_I Q_I)}
$$
Here $\beta = \frac{1}{T}$ is the inverse temperature, Lagrange multiplier, dual to energy, and $\beta \mu_I$ are dual to other conserved quantities.

One can add to the exponent any conserved quantity, however, they need to be independent. If you have several conserved quantities of the same kind, like some flavor conservation, you may add chemical potential to each of the conserved flavors, and to their linear combination $\alpha Q_1 + \beta Q_2$.

If the system has rotational symmetry one also can include term $\beta \omega J$, where $\omega$ is angular velocity and $J$ is the angular momentum.